# Python- STL File Reduction

Tags: python, numpy-stl

I want to make a python script that reduces number of triangles in a STL file while preserving shape in python. Is there some module which can do this operation?

Answer (score 0):

PyMesh has the ability to split and collapse edges, which can be used to decimate a mesh, as seen on [their website](https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mesh_processing.html#remeshing) (with a code example found [here](https://github.com/PyMesh/PyMesh/blob/master/scripts/fix_mesh.py), specifically the `fix_mesh` function).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38197212/7564109) is a Stack Overflow post which explains how to decimate using the VTK library.